# Odd leg swelling

Tags: inflammation, swelling, legs

34 year old male. Had a long flight to Cancun Dec 2015, when I arrived my feet and lower legs began to get extremely swollen and red and put me out of commission for the first 3 or 4 days of my vacation.  I saw two doctors there and they couldn't identify it, they thought it was some sort of cellulitis.

Ever since that time, I started getting them regularly.  It started occurring monthly (mid=Jan 2016 was the next time) but around Sept '16 it's been daily.  My shoes hardly fit - I don't tie my laces anymore,  - this IS with compression socks warn each day.  The socks used to help, but now the swelling seems to just force the socks to expand, too.

I've gone through two primary care doc's in this time, and I had two docs in Cancun look at me.  I've had a rheumatalogist specialist look at it, I've had multiple ultrasounds and X-rays on my legs.  My PCP had me go to the ER in Sept for redness developing and I ended up being checked in for 3 days with bag after bag of different antibiotic IVs (at least 3 or 4 types) and then I was sent home with amoxicillin (which I discovered I was allergic to). Since then, I haven't had a single day where the swelling wasn't there.

I get intense leg cramps, my toes will get sharp pains and go numb/purple sometimes.

The various doctors keep suggesting Buergers and Cellulitis and maybe some other stuff, but I wasn't diagnosed with anything (why not?).  After some time with this and lots of reading, I don't think it's Buergers anymore.

I had extremely high IgA and ALT levels on my blood test results 3 times, then suddenly they were normal on the 4th test (not sure if this is anything related).

Does anyone have any idea what I could do to help the problem?  Or any idea what could be causing something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Here on Health.SE, we don't do personal diagnosis. Only a doctor can examine you thoroughly and give you a profound diagnosis. If you don't agree with your doctor, **ask for a second opinion**

Comment: This is the wrong forum to ask these type of questions. My piece of advice to you is to find a better doctor. So many local doctors have no idea what to do when they encounter a not so common issue. https://health.clevelandclinic.org/2015/07/what-you-should-know-about-swelling-in-your-legs/